# When it is better in Java to use declaration with full name including library at one line, not importing anything in the top?

Tags: java, import, declaration

When such way of declaration

```
java.util.ArrayList example = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

is preferable than

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

?

Comment: Ummm ... do >>you<< think it is preferable to do this?  Really?

Answer (score 9):

Very rarely.

I would only fully qualify if I was using two classes with the same name but different packages. e.g. `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`

In this situation I'd simply import the more commonly used, and fully qualify the less-well used one. And/or refactor such that the two don't co-exist (if possible and practical).

Answer (score 6):

When you are using two or more different classes with same name but which are from different packages you need to use fully qualified name to tell JVM which one you want to use.
For example while using `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` in same place.

If you are not using such **different_but_same_name_classes** then import is preferable over fully qualified path name.